# Pandas to_numeric(errors='coerce') does not convert invalid value to nan

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset "app_metadata.csv" with three column: item_id, category, description. item_id is integer number, category is a string, and description is a string. I loaded the dataset with the following code

```
app_metadata_df = pd.read_csv(app_metadata_csv_path)
```

However there is broken data in the dataset, for example there exist a row at which item_id is not a number but a text. I want to remove rows with invalid item_id value and convert the item_id column datatype to int. The following is what i have tried, first i call pd.to_numeric with errors='coerce'

```
app_metadata_df.loc["item_id"] = pd.to_numeric(app_metadata_df["item_id"], errors='coerce')
```

Then i drop NA value

```
app_metadata_df.loc["item_id"] = app_metadata_df.loc["item_id"].dropna()
```

And finally call the astype(int) to convert the datatype to int:

```
app_metadata_df.loc["item_id"] = app_metadata_df["item_id"].astype(int)
```

However, it throws the following error

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'So'
```

It looks like to_numeric does not convert some invalid value to NAN. Why is this happening and how do i fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
app_metadata_df = pd.read_csv(app_metadata_csv_path)

app_metadata_df['item_id'] = pd.to_numeric(app_metadata_df["item_id"], errors='coerce')
app_metadata_df = app_metadata_df[app_metadata_df['item_id'].notna()].reset_index()

app_metadata_df["item_id"] = app_metadata_df["item_id"].astype(int)
```

###### `>>> print(app_metadata_df)`

```
       index   item_id            category  \
0          0  593676.0  HEALTH_AND_FITNESS   
1          1  601235.0                GAME   
2          2  860079.0       COMMUNICATION   
3          3   64855.0       VIDEO_PLAYERS   
4          4  597756.0             MEDICAL   
...      ...       ...                 ...   
98577  98594  683377.0               TOOLS   
98578  98595  862905.0             FINANCE   
98579  98596  165878.0     MUSIC_AND_AUDIO   
98580  98597  683417.0         PHOTOGRAPHY   
98581  98598  703224.0                GAME   

                                             description  
0      Abs Workout, designed by professional fitness ...  
1      The best building game on android is free to d...  
2      Tamil Actress Stickers app has 200 + Tamil her...  
3      The simplest VLC Remote you'll ever find. Peri...  
4      This is the official mobile app of the Nationa...  
...                                                  ...  
98577  endoscope app for android an app to connect wi...  
98578  Acerca de esta app<br>La App OCA está pensada ...  
98579  This app provides free downloading of audio sh...  
98580  <b>Water Paint : Colour Effect</b><br><br>Want...  
98581  DIAMOND CRUSH with spectacular graphics and ex...  

[98582 rows x 4 columns]
```

###### `>>> print(app_metadata_df.info())`

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 98582 entries, 0 to 98581
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------       --------------  ----- 
 0   index        98582 non-null  int64 
 1   item_id      98582 non-null  int32 
 2   category     98582 non-null  object
 3   description  98582 non-null  object
dtypes: int32(1), int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 2.6+ MB
```

Comment: do i need to replace 'app_metadata_df['item_id'] =' with 'app_metadata_df.loc['item_id'] ='  ?? 
# https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy . Anyway on my way to try this

Comment: i have tried this, when i try to convert it to int with astype(int) it still throws the same error https://pastebin.com/LGiE5e1f

Comment: Check out my updated answer. You're using `app_metadata_df.loc["item_id"] = app_metadata_df["item_id"].astype(int)` instead of `app_metadata_df["item_id"] = app_metadata_df["item_id"].astype(int)`. That's why pandas throws that error.

Comment: I have tried to copy your code exactly without changes, it works! thanks . But i wonder what is the difference?

Comment: sorry i used loc earlier because during my coding earlier pandas keep throwing SettingWithCopyWarning so i started using .loc everywhere since then.

Comment: No worries. To handle `SettingWithCopyWarning` you just need to reassign your `app_metadata_df` (as I did in the third line of my code) or use `.copy()`.

Comment: How does using .loc and not using it have a big difference? i still dont understand, can you please explain it? if you dont have time i'm fine your solution worked i will still accept your answer

Comment: When you run `app_metadata_df.loc["item_id"] = pd.to_numeric(app_metadata_df["item_id"], errors='coerce')
` , it creates a new index (see, https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNXG8.png). Look at the last line and how `item_id` became an index. So now, when you run `app_metadata_df.loc["item_id"]` you will get a null serie (see, https://i.stack.imgur.com/08PhQ.png)

Comment: thank so much, i still dont understand on why this is a thing on pandas (bad design or i just dont understand pandas thoroughly) , but i understand what happened now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
app_metadata_df['item_id']=pd.to_numeric(app_metadata_df["item_id"], errors='coerce') 
app_metadata_df.dropna(subset=['item_id'], inplace=True)
app_metadata_df
```